# Managing resource in Java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, load-balancing

Suppose:

1. There are 10 tasks
2. There are 3 threads
3. There are 3 arrayLists
4. Every threads related to 1 arrayList

My question is : how to manage the resources? for example, first step 3 tasks will be executed using 3 threads and 3 arrayLists. Then whenever a thread is available, the 4th task will be executed along with available arrayList. How to do that in Java? please give me reference or source code.

```
public class NewClass {

    private Queue<Integer> availableCore = new LinkedList();

    public void manage() throws InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new ArrayList<>());
        data.add(new ArrayList<>());
        data.add(new ArrayList<>());

        availableCore.add(0);
        availableCore.add(1);
        availableCore.add(2);

        ArrayList<Calculate> allThreads = new ArrayList<>();
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(3);
        int threadCount = -1;

        int numOfTask = 10;

        while (numOfTask > 0) {
            if (!availableCore.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(availableCore.element());
                threadCount++;
                int core = availableCore.remove();
                allThreads.add(new Calculate(data.get(core), numOfTask, core));
                es.execute(allThreads.get(threadCount));
                numOfTask--;
            }
        }

        es.shutdown();
        boolean finished = es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println("Done\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(data.get(i));
        }
    }

    public class Calculate extends Thread {

        private ArrayList<Integer> data;
        private int start;
        private int core;

        public Calculate(ArrayList<Integer> data, int start, int core) {
            this.data = data;
            this.start = start;
            this.core = core;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.data.add(start);
            availableCore.add(this.core);
        }

        public int getCore() {
            return core;
        }
    }
}
```

This code above is representing my actual problem. When I tried to run several times, sometimes I got an error in "availableCore.element()". It said that availableCore is empty, but I made a condition that make sure it is not empty.

```
if (!availableCore.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(availableCore.element());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is : how to manage the resources? for example, first step
> 4 tasks will be executed using 4 core and 4 arrayList. Then whenever a
> core is available, the 5th task will be executed along with available
> arrayList. How to do that in Java? please give me reference or source
> code.

AFAIK, natively, Java does not have features to explicitly map a given thread to a given core (*i.e.,* thread affinity). You can do it via explicit system calls such as in Linux OS using the [taskset](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html) command. But this would require you to do a lot of working, and possibility lose portability in the way.

You would be better off using higher-level Java abstracts (e.g., [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)) to deal with those low levels details for you. Send the tasks to a Thread Pool using the `ExecutorService` let the pool and **ultimately** the OS Threads scheduler deal with the mapping between threads/task.

Btw even using Java Thread Pools, there is no guarantee that the threads will be nicely mapped to separate cores.

Other languages, such as C/C++ might provide you with libraries that allow you to explicitly map cores to threads, for instance using [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org) [thread affinity features](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/omp-affinity.html).

---

Based on your comment :

> If I only send the tasks to a Thread Pool without managing the
> arrayList, it will consume a lot of memory. Suppose 1 have 100 tasks
> then it will need 100 arrayLists.. I want to reduce the memory
> consumption by using only 4 arrayList to be reused whenever a task is
> completed.

It sounds to me that you want to implement the [producer-consumer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). One thread will be responsible for adding work to the Queue (i.e., `ArrayList`s) will the other threads request that work from the Queue and consume it.

Comment: It is working producer and consumer pattern. Thank you very much @dreamcrash.

Answer (score 1):

As said [@dreamcrash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366871/dreamcrash) we can't map a thread to a core. But, you might use `ExecutorService` for your task. In this case, you will use thread per task, and your code will look like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Cores {

    private static ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> first = List.of("1", "2", "3");
        List<String> second = List.of("1", "2", "3");
        List<String> third = List.of("1", "2", "3");
        List<String> fourth = List.of("1", "2", "3");
        List<String> fifth = List.of("1", "2", "3");

        sendToExecutor(first, second, third, fourth, fifth);

        service.shutdown();
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public static void sendToExecutor(List<String>... lists) {
        for (List<String> list : lists) {
            service.execute(() -> handleWholeList(list));
        }
    }

    public static void handleWholeList(List<String> strings) {
        strings.forEach(s -> System.out.printf("String %s handled in thread %s%n", s, Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    }
}
```

And instead of hardcoded 4 threads:

```
private static ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

you could use the number of available processors:

```
private static ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```